# What should I use the Non-greedy match in this case

Tags: python

Assume I have a string which includes some data fields that are separated by "|", like
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|

My purpose is to get the 8th field. This is what I'm doing:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^\s+(\|.*?\|){8}')
match = pattern.match(test_line)
if match:
   print:match.group(8)
```

But looks like it can not match. I know in this case I need to use ? for non-greedy match, but why I can not get the 8th field?

Thanks

Comment: It might help you to realize `(\|.*?\|){8}` matches not your string, but `|1||2||3||4||..`.

Comment: Thanks. You just reminds me that I can use splitting. :)
But still, how will regex work for this case

Comment: To Wrikken: Yes. you are right. But the problem here is it can not match anything, looks like the match() returned false

Comment: @JieLiu yes, that's exactly the point. Your regex can't possibly match your string because it requires *two* `|` between adjacent items by having `|` at the beginning *and* end of the repetition group.

Comment: That is what I am saying, your regex will never match your data because of this. Of course you _should_ just split, but for the heck if it (I assume you have the `^\s+` in there for good reasons... might as well be `\s*`..): `^\s*\|(?:(.*?)\|){8}`

Answer (score 5):

Regex might be complicating this problem rather than simplifying it.  A simple way to get an eighth item from a | delimited string is **using split()**:

```
a = '|here|is|some|data|separated|by|bars|hooray!|'

print a.split('|')[8]
```

RETURNS

```
hooray!
```

**Using regex**, one way to get it would be:

```
import re
a = '|here|is|some|data|separated|by|bars|hooray!|'

pattern = re.compile(r'([^\|]+)')
match = pattern.findall(a)
print match[7]
```

RETURNS

```
hooray!
```

Comment: Great answer. But note that the OP's sample input also has pipe characters at the start and end, not just between the elements. So, `a.split('|')` is going to be [`'', '1', '2', '3', …]`, so he wants `a.split('|')[8].

Comment: Also, you don't need (and shouldn't use) `re.findall(pattern, a)` with a compiled pattern; just use `pattern.findall(a)`.

Comment: The head and tail pipes luckily don't affect the result, but avoiding `re.` is good, thanks.

Comment: Yes they do. Try `print('|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|').split('|')` and see what you get.

Comment: My apologies, I meant that it doesnt affect the regex result, but it does indeed affect the split result.  With the OPs continued emphasis on the regex solution, I overlooked the split one, which definitely should have your edit.  Thanks again.